# How to execute an event before a routerLink executes in a button

Tags: angular

I am trying to execute an event before a routerLink in angular 4.

I'm interested in the button at the very bottom of my page.

```
<div >
<button class="btn btn-primary"
(click)="createTeacher()"
 routerLink ='/teacher'
 >Submit</button>
</div>
```

I want to know if there is a way to make sure the `(click)="createTeacher()"` event happens before the routerlink shifts the page, so the recent create will appear in that new list.

```html
<form class="teacher">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input required [(ngModel)]=teacher.name name="name"
        #name="ngModel" 
        id ="name" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" 
          *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
          Name is required
        </div>
      <label for="">About Me</label>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]=teacher.aboutMe name="about" 
        #name="ngModel"
        id="about" 
        cols="30" 
        rows="10" 
        class="form-control">
      </textarea>
      <label for="">Location</label>
      <input required [(ngModel)]=teacher.location name="loc"
      #name="ngModel"
      id="loc"
      type="text"
      class="form-control">
      <label for="">Email</label>
      <input required [(ngModel)]=teacher.email name="email"
      #name="ngModel"
      id="email"
      type="text"
      class="form-control">
      <label for="">Phone</label>
      <input required [(ngModel)]=teacher.phone name="phone"
      #name="ngModel"
      id="phone"
      type="text"
      class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div >
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="createTeacher()"
     routerLink ='/teacher'
     >Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Following is my component that the Html is associated with.

```js
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import ITeacherModelAngular from '../Share/ITeacherModelAngular';
import { TeacherService } from '../teacher-service.service';
import TeacherModel from '../Share/TeacherModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-teach-form',
  templateUrl: './new-teach-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-teach-form.component.css']
})
export class NewTeachFormComponent implements OnInit {
  teacher: TeacherModel;
  constructor(private service$: TeacherService) {
    this.teacher = new TeacherModel();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createTeacher() {
    this.service$.createTeacher(this.teacher);
    this.service$.getTeacherIndex();
  }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: You could remove the `routerLink` param and just do a `router.navigate('your-url')` in the `createTeacher` method? That why you control the order of actions better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the event **createTeacher()** will be triggered before routerLink is executed, but in case you are dealing with a post call in **this.service$.createTeacher(this.teacher);** you may be navigating before the post call is successful. 
If you don't want to navigate until the post call is successful. you can handle the route inside **createTeacher()** method.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

inject it to constructor

```
constructor(private service$: TeacherService, private router: Router)
```

and in the method use router.navigate();

```
createTeacher() {
    this.service$.createTeacher(this.teacher);
    this.service$.getTeacherIndex();
    // trigger the route only when createTeacher() is resolved.
    this.router.navigate(['/teacher']);
  }
```

Comment: This really helped an lead me to how to fix my problem. the exact edit i did to make it work was this Thank you for your advice.                                 
                 
`this.service$.createTeacher(this.teacher).subscribe(response => {
         console.log(response.json());
          this.route.navigate(['/teacher']);
       });`